# Access Azure DevOps variables from Android Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, versioning

While building my Android App inside [DevOps Pipeline](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/devops/pipelines/), I want to access the predefined [Azure DevOps variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) from inside my gradle script, which looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// When running on the CI, this will return the build-number. Otherwise use 1
def buildNumber = System.getenv("Build.BuildNumber") as Integer ?: 1

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode buildNumber
        versionName "1.0." + buildNumber
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    ...
}
```

On [Bitrise](https://www.bitrise.io/), the call `def buildNumber = System.getenv("BITRISE_BUILD_NUMBER") as Integer ?: 1` worked just fine, but I have no idea, how to access the [Build.BuildNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#primary-artifact-variables) variable in Azure DevOps Pipeline.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to access the variables. The trick is to replace the dot with an underscore and lowercase letters with uppercase letters.

So

```
def buildNumber = System.getenv("Build.BuildNumber") as Integer ?: 1
```

becomes

```
def buildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_BUILDNUMBER") as Integer ?: 1
```

And given that Build.BuildNumber looks like 20191129.16, which is an invalid version code, I switched to

```
def buildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_BUILDID") as Integer ?: 1
```

Comment: Azure mention that in their docs when using power shell scripts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I want to increment my build version and number which exist in the gradle from my pipeline. In order to publish it to play store. So can you please add a snippet about your pipeline?

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish You can see the full code in the question above. What else are you looking for?